# How to download Firefox extension as .xpi-file manually from another browser?

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-extensions

How is it possible to download a firefox extension as `.xpi`-file from the official site https://addons.mozilla.org/ if not using firefox as a browser?

https://addons.mozilla.org/ in this case just shows "Only with Firefox—Get Firefox Now" instead of the install/ download button -- and when I click there, I am prompted to download firefox. But I want to get the extension (e.g. to install it manually on another computer, or in another browser like Pale Moon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that now there appeared a link "Download file" below the "Download Firefox and get the extension" button, which directly gives the `.xpi` file, e.g.:
[`https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/4150911/popupoff-2.1.3.xpi`](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/4150911/popupoff-2.1.3.xpi).

Answer (score 5):

You can download an extension from Firefox:

1. Go to the extension page, for example, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/?src=homepage-collection-featured.
2. Right-click on Add to Firefox button and select Copy Link Location.
3. Paste the link to the address bar, then insert "/type:attachment" after file number: "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3390826/ghostery_privacy_ad_blocker-8.4.2-an+fx.xpi?src=homepage-collection-featured" -> "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3390826/type:attachment/ghostery_privacy_ad_blocker-8.4.2-an+fx.xpi?src=homepage-collection-featured".
4. Open the link.

... or from any other browser:

1. Open the link to the extension (ex, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1password-x-password-manager )
2. Under the button " Download Firefox and get the extension " click " Download File. "

Comment: The 3rd step is not necessary if the extension link is opened in Firefox. Also the `?src=homepage-collection-featured` part can be removed from the first link.

Comment: The 3rd step is necessary if you want to download the extension instead of install it.

Comment: @GCRaistlin: But the question is how to download it _without_ firefox. I have a reason to not use firefox itself.

Comment: The answer is updated.

Comment: If the addon is already added and you want to still download it from firefox go to the add-on page and view source. Search for xpi which will provide you the link to file (with weird `u002F` characters added). Clean the link & pass it to another extension such as Downthemall to download the xpi file

Comment: i think you can change step 2 - instead of copy link - do right mouse button click and select 'save link as' - that allows to save xpi - that is it. by the way, same works for already installed extensions - you can right mouse button click on 'remove' and select 'save link as...'

Answer (score -1):

Let me Summarize In Simple Words :

1 . Go to the extension page. [ for example, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/?src=homepage-collection-featured ]

2 . Right-click on Add to Firefox button and select Copy Link Location.

3 . Paste the link in another tab.

4 . Insert "/type:attachment" after the numbers written in the link. [ for example ------------------------>

From

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3390826/ghostery_privacy_ad_blocker-8.4.2-an+fx.xpi

To

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3390826/type:attachment/ghostery_privacy_ad_blocker-8.4.2-an+fx.xpi

5 . Now , Open the new link by clicking "enter" .

6 . Then the file will be downloaded in the Downloads Folder/Location in xpi-file format .

Comment: This answer does not apply since "*Right-click on Add to Firefox button and select Copy Link Location.*" only shows in Firefox browsers, but at the time of asking the question the addon site behaved differently when visiting not with a firefox browser; that button is replaced with a button to download Firefox.